# Clean python return assignment

Tags: python

I have a method that returns multiple items.

```
def multiReturn():
   return 1,2,3,4
```

and Im assigning it on one line

```
one, two, three, four = multiReturn()
```

Is there a way to cleanup the above line

Something like:

```
one,
two,
three,
four = multiReturn()
```

because I have some variable names that have gotten large and the width of the page is bothering me.

Any ideas to clean it up

Comment: In my humble opinion, your situation is a strong hint the behaviour you want to implement with that tuple should be abstracted in its own class, with `multiReturn()` as its constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use parentheses:

```
(
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four
) = range(4)
```

Comment: However, this is hardly cleaner.

Comment: @delnan Nope... in this case - it's less clear than the original... ;) Just showing the "correct" way to do multi-line grouping

Answer (score 8):

If you're returning so many items already, consider creating a data structure of some sort. A class should be fine, but if you consider it overkill, you can use a dict or even a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
# First define the structure
myStruct = namedtuple('myStruct', ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'])

# Then use it
def multiReturn():
    return myStruct(1,2,3,4)

# No unpacking required!
this_is_awesome = multiReturn()
```

Comment: I like this as it also has the advantage of making the return value from the function a little bit more self-documenting...

Answer (score 2):

Use a backslash at the end of each line.

```
one, \
two, \
three, \
four = multiReturn()
```

Comment: It was taught to me recently on SO that when you do this, it tells the interpreter to ignore the next character, which, in the usual case when using backslashes like this, will be the newline character. However, it could be another character if you make a typo or put a comment there. So, be warned.

Answer (score -1):

Shorten your variable names.

No, really. If you can't fit usual width constraints, it 's a hint that you need some refactoring.  Let me get to that.

To remain clear, names should be kept short.  On the other hand, you need them to describe the value they are holding, or code they are performing (i case of functions etc.)

If it's hard for you to describe the value *and* keep the name short, it means that for any person
reading your code it will be most probably even *much harder* to read and understand, since you make
them concentrate on multiple things.

For comaprison, if I am to write something like:

```
class App():

    def __init__(self):

        self.config = {}
        self.error = ""
        # ...
        configDatabaseConnection = mydbmodule.conect(credentials)
        configQuery = "this and that"
        config = configDatabaseConnection.query(configQuery)
        configDatabaseConnectionErrorString = (configDatabaseConection.error)
        if configDatabaseConnectionErrorString:
            raise configError(configDatabaseConnectionErrorString)
        # ...
```

it normally means that I need to separate the configutation to another method, and use that instead:

```
class App():

    def __init__(self, credentials):

        self.config = self.load_config(credentials)
        self.error = ""
        # ...

        self.load_config()

     def load_config(self, credentials):

        conn = mydbmodule.conect(credentials)
        q = "this and that"
        config = conn.query(q)
        if conn.error:
            raise configError(conn.error)
        self.config = config
```

which is much more readable, and allows adding more logic to configuration procedure (say, fall-backs, reading from file instead of db...) without cluttering the gist of my code.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner Yes, it was a little bit *too brief*.  I tried to elaborate on that.